# Quicksight refreshing Anomaly dashboards for real time data

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-quicksight

Currently AWS QuickSight has an option to refresh the Dataset from S3 using scheduled refresh.
Once the data is refreshed, normal dashboards (visuals chart) gets updated with new data.

For Anomaly dashboards (insights chart), currently if the data is refreshed, we need to manually trigger the "run now" and later run "update".

Is their a way or option to automate the refresh for Anomaly dashboard as well? Can we trigger it using programming?

Comment: I am merely trying to figure out whether a user of a published dashboard can themselves manually refresh the data, say, every minute or so.  AWS provides a lot of documentation and videos that discuss *creating* dashboards, but almost nothing about the capabilities of the dashboard *users*.

Comment: Do you need to use SPICE? Direct queries/reads will always load the current state of the database.

Answer (score 2):

I used AWS CLI with below command:

```
aws quicksight create-ingestion --aws-account-id <YOUR-AWS-ACCOUNT --ingestion-id <UNIQUE-ID> --data-set-id <DATASET-ID> --region <REGION>
```

--aws-accout-id -> The account to your desired quicksight

--ingestion-id -> This can be any unique name(string)

--data-set-id -> Go to QuckSight dataset to find the unique string

--region -> Your region for the aws-account

Also I did the same using Python boto3:

```
import boto3
import calendar
import time

client = boto3.client(
    'quicksight',
    region_name='us-east-1'
)


#to create unique number
ingestionID = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())
response = client.create_ingestion(
    DataSetId='12345e-d123-4123-b1a1-12f30154b123',
    IngestionId=str(ingestionID),
    AwsAccountId='123456789123'
)


print(response)
```